# How can I find and replace text in XML using Perl?

Tags: xml, perl, replace, find

My XML file looks something like this:

```
<doc>
    <RU1>
       <conf> 
              <prop name="a" val="http://a.org/a.html> 
       </conf>    
    </RU1>
    <RAU1>
     <conf> 
              <prop name="a" val="http://a.org/a.html> 
       </conf>
    </RAU1>
    <RU2>
     <conf> 
              <prop name="a" val="http://a.org/a.html> 
       </conf>
    </RU2>
</doc>
```

I want to replace "a.org" in the value of the prop field, under all parent tags which start with RU in perl, with "b.com".How do I obtain the changed as an xml file?

Comment: Your XML is malformed.  The values are missing quotes and the prop tag is not closed.  Is this a mistake, or do you want to parse malformed XML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your XML is well formed (it isn't) you can use [a number of CPAN modules](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?recommended_xml_modules) for the job.  Most of the will involve parsing the document, finding your bit with an XPath query, and printing the document out again.

Here's an example with XML::Twig.  I had to fix up the XML to get it to parse.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'conf/prop' => sub { $_->{att}{val} =~ s/a.org/b.org/; }
    },
    pretty_print => "indented"
);
$twig->parse(join "", <DATA>);

$twig->print;


__END__
<foo>
<RU1>
   <conf>
          <prop name="a" val="http://a.org/a.html" />
   </conf>
</RU1>
<RAU1>
   <conf>
          <prop name="a" val="http://a.org/a.html" />
   </conf>
</RAU1>
<RU2>
 <conf> 
          <prop name="a" val="http://a.org/a.html" />
   </conf>
</RU2>
</foo>
```

Comment: I agree with your answer but it should be noted that every manipulation involving parsing, replacement and then serialization loses stuff: entities are expanded, whitespace can be rearranged, encoding may change, etc. If you edit your XML by hand, it can be a big issue.

Answer (score 4):

Grab an XML parser off the CPAN and use it. They're there for a reason.

Once you've done that, it's some fairly simple XPath expressions to get the nodes you want, and then some quick text replacement on the specific attributes themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Using the following stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'RU')]//prop/@val">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-aorg" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replace-aorg">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, 'a.org')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, 'a.org')"/>
        <xsl:text>b.com</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-aorg">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, 'a.org')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and adjusting your XML document to

```
<doc>
<RU1>
   <conf> 
          <prop name="a" val="http://a.org/a.html" /> 
   </conf>    
</RU1>
<RAU1>
 <conf> 
          <prop name="a" val="http://a.org/a.html" /> 
   </conf>
</RAU1>
<RU2>
 <conf> 
          <prop name="a" val="http://a.org/a.html" /> 
   </conf>
</RU2>
</doc>
```

Output:

```
$ xsltproc sty.xml doc.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
<RU1>
   <conf>
          <prop name="a">http://b.com/a.html</prop>
   </conf>
</RU1>
<RAU1>
 <conf>
          <prop name="a" val="http://a.org/a.html"/>
   </conf>
</RAU1>
<RU2>
 <conf>
          <prop name="a">http://b.com/a.html</prop>
   </conf>
</RU2>
</doc>
```

So from Perl, that would be something such as

```
system("xsltproc", "style.xsl", "doc.xml") == 0
  or warn "$0: xsltproc exited " . ($? >> 8);
```

Comment: ITS SO SIMPLE AND SUCCINCT! :P

Comment: At least the Perl part is simple and succinct.

Comment: XSL is for the people who think XML isn't complicated enough. :)