# XML search and replace values using perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML and it has a "-" along with one space at the beginning of header and tag values under it .. I need to replace "_ " with nothing (NULL) and delete the second line of the XML which is `<HEADER ASOF_DATE="2/15/2013" CREATE_DATE="2/17/2013" RECORDS="5">`

and under NAME column or SHORT_DESC column in each record of XML there might be or might not be "&" .. if it exists in NAME column it has to be replaced with "$$$" and save the file ...

Below is the XML file ..

```
- <HEADER>
- <HEADER ASOF_DATE="2/15/2013" CREATE_DATE="2/17/2013" RECORDS="5">
- <TAG>
<SHORT_DESC>XXX & CO MTN RegS</SHORT_DESC> 
<NAME>XXX & CO</NAME> 
</TAG>
- <TAG>
<SHORT_DESC>XYZ & DEV</SHORT_DESC> 
<NAME>XYZ & DEVELOP</NAME> 
</TAG>
- <TAG>
<SHORT_DESC>AB&C INC</SHORT_DESC> 
<NAME>AB&C INC</NAME> 
</TAG>
- <TAG>
<SHORT_DESC>AAA BBB & COMPANY</SHORT_DESC> 
<NAME>AAA BBB & COMPANY</NAME> 
</TAG>
- <TAG>
<SHORT_DESC>ABC XYZ</SHORT_DESC> 
<NAME>ABC XYZ</NAME> 
</TAG>
- </HEADER>
```

The o/p should be ..

```
<HEADER>
<TAG>
<SHORT_DESC>XXX $$$ CO MTN RegS</SHORT_DESC> 
<NAME>XXX $$$ CO</NAME> 
</TAG>
<TAG>
<SHORT_DESC>XYZ $$$ DEV</SHORT_DESC> 
<NAME>XYZ $$$ DEVELOP</NAME> 
</TAG>
<TAG>
<SHORT_DESC>AB$$$C INC</SHORT_DESC> 
<NAME>AB$$$C INC</NAME> 
</TAG>
<TAG>
<SHORT_DESC>AAA BBB $$$ COMPANY</SHORT_DESC> 
<NAME>AAA BBB $$$ COMPANY</NAME> 
</TAG>
<TAG>
<SHORT_DESC>ABC XYZ</SHORT_DESC> 
<NAME>ABC XYZ</NAME> 
</TAG>
</HEADER>
```

Below is the code  ...but its not saving the xml file with the changes

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $tag = 'SHORT_DESC';

open my $fh, '<test.xml' or die $!;

foreach (<$fh>) {
  s/&/@@@/g;
  s/- //g;
  print $_;
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052179/how-can-i-find-and-replace-text-in-xml-using-perl)

Comment: Show the Perl code you've done so far.

Comment: Agree with the first answer referenced above, XML::Twig is good

Comment: This is the below perl code which i'm using ..but it's not modifying the xml file ...                                      #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $tag = 'SHORT_DESC';

open my $fh, '<test.xml' or die $!;

foreach (<$fh>) {
  s/&/@@@/g;
  s/- //g;
  print $_;
}
close $fh;

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the file because you are only opening it for reading.

You need to open another file to write the output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $tag = 'SHORT_DESC';

open my $input_file, '<', 'test.xml' or die $!;
open my $output_file, '>', 'test_out.xml' or die $!;

my $input;
{
  local $/;               #Set record separator to undefined.
  $input = <$input_file>; #This allows the whole input file to be read at once.
}

$input =~ s/&/@@@/g;
$input =~ s/^- (?=<)//gm;
$input =~ s/<header[^>]*>\K\s*<header[^>]*>//gis;
print {$output_file} $input;

close $input_file or die $!;
close $output_file or die $!;
```

*Note: it is possible to edit files in-place in Perl. But I would recommend writing to another file in most cases.  It is more convenient for testing and safer--you don't risk losing the original.*

I modified your regex:

```
s/^- (?=<)//g
```

I added a `^` so that you only remove it at the beginning of the line, and a look-ahead,  `(?=<)`, to make sure that it only removes it when it comes before a tag.

Deleting the second `<header>` tag is a bit more complicated. It depends on what you exactly want to do.  Here is one approach:

```
s/<header[^>]*>\K\s*<header[^>]*>//gis;
```

Whenever it finds two header tags separated only by white space, it deletes the second one. `\K` preserves whatever matched before it; thus, only the second one is deleted.

As soon as you get the XML file into a valid form, you should use an XML parsing module to do any further manipulation.  [`XML::Twig` is a good one](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.42/Twig.pm).

Comment: Thanks Dan for the inputs... the script is now working as expected and its well formatted .. but the second line of the xml is still not getting deleted... my purpose is to parse this formatted xml to do some other operations ..so I would like to just delete the second line since it has just information fields only ...please help ..

Comment: @Srini, sorry for the mistake in the original code.  The problem was that the pattern needed to match on multiple lines, but the code was only reading one line of the file at a time.  I changed the code to read the entire file into one variable.

Comment: Thanks Dan ... I'm getting syntax error while running the code ..syntax error at test1.pl line 22, near "$;

close"
Execution of test1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @Srini, oops there was a typo on that line.  Supposed to be `$input`

Comment: Thanks very much Dan .. I added print {$output_file} $input; then it worked as expected ...