# Regex in xml not working as expected

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I am novice here and I am trying to search and replace a string in a xml file which is as given below:

```
<name>xxx.yyy_zzz</name>
      <constructor_arguments />
      <parameters>
        <parameter>
          <name>Name</name>
          <string>
            <value>yyy</value>
          </string>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
          <name>abc</name>
          <bool>
            <value>false</value>
          </bool>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
          <name>abcd</name>
          <bool>
            <value>true</value>
          </bool>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
          <name>aa</name>
          <integer>
            <value>10</value>
          </integer>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
          <name>bb</name>
          <integer>
            <value>100</value>
          </integer>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
          <name>runtime_disabled</name>
          <bool>
            <value>false</value>
          </bool>
```

I have tried the following to change runtime_disabled value to true but it did not happen which I expect to happen, can anyone tell why is it so and provide suitable solution for the same to work

```
$data=~ s/(xxx\.i\yyy\_zzz\s*?<\/name>(.+?)runtime_disabled\s*?<\/name>\s*?<bool>\s*?<value>\s*?<value>.*?<\/value>)/$1true$2/g;
```

Comment: seems like you are trying to get names so always better to use parser for xml docs try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052179/how-can-i-find-and-replace-text-in-xml-using-perl

Comment: Trying to parse XML with a regex is a recipe for pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing well-formed XML should practically *always* be done using modules. Much has been said about that over time, see for example [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg?rq=1), among many others.  I also hear that [truly bad things may come to pass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4653379)  otherwise.

Here is an example of how to do what you ask using [XML::libXML](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eshlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0128/LibXML.pod). Another excellent module is [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm). I completed your sample so to make it a well-formed XML file (shown below code).

```
use strict 'all';
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;    

my $file = 'file.xml';

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file, no_blanks => 1); 

# Form the XPath expression used to find the 'name' nodes
my $xpath = '//doc/constructor_arguments/parameters/parameter/name';

foreach my $node ($doc->findnodes($xpath)) 
{
    # Select the particular 'name' tag that is needed
    if ($node->to_literal eq 'runtime_disabled') 
    {   
        # Query the parent node, for <name>'s sibling <bool>
        foreach my $bval ($node->parentNode->findnodes('./bool/value/text()')) 
        {
            my $content = $bval->toString;
            $content =~ s/false/true/;
            $bval->setData($content);
        }
    }   
}

# Write a new file with the change
$doc->toFile('changed_' . $file, 1);
```

This is meant to be basic, there are quite a few other ways to do the same.

The posted sample was padded as follows

```
<doc>
... posted text ...
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </constructor_arguments>
</doc>
```

Comment: Since it is a XML file I am moving to the method you are suggesting and  the eg., mentioned is found to be working.

Comment: @Emman  Great -- parsing XML by hand (regex) leads to no end of trouble. By the time you'd clean up one such file you'll learn how to use a module, and then you are taken care of. With either of the two modules I mention you have full control over everything, while simple things are simple.  It is instructive reading some of the posts on this topic.  I'll add a few links to them.